# How to run javascript if iPhone is not in full screen mode?

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications, mobile, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'd like to run this script, but only when iPhone is not in full screen mode.

```
<script>
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
    addEventListener("load", function() {
        setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
        }, false);
    }
function hideURLbar() {
window.scrollTo(0, 1);}
</script>
```

So how can I do that? (Could [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm) help?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var hidescreen = ("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone)

if (hidescreen  && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) {
    addEventListener("load", function() {
    setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0);
    }, false);
}
function hideURLbar() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: I remowed closing parenthesis `var hidescreen = ("standalone" in window.navigator) && !window.navigator.standalone` and it's working! Thanks!